# Why can't grails run two applications on the same port?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

With Tomcat or Glassfish, there is no problem with deploying multiple apps on port 8080.  But if you try to do a grails run-app on multiple apps (without specifying different ports) at the same time, you will receive a JVM Bind Exception.

Why is grails run-app different from deploying a .WAR to a container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no grails expert, but Tomcat and Glassfish are one process/application bound to one port. Then they host different applications (web/enterprise) running in the same VM, and route requests using the context root for example.

I suspect grails `run-app` starts a new application as a new process/in a new JVM instance and tries to bind it to the port. If there's already a binding, that won't work.

Comment: That is exactly what happens. If you have a tomcat server already set up and just want to install your grails application in it you can use the 'grails tomcat deploy' and 'grails tomcat undeploy' scripts to run it there, but you lose the automatic reloading feature.

Answer (score 7):

> deploying a .WAR to a container

The container itself is bound to a port.  The container (Tomcat, Glassfish, whatever) has the ability to host multiple applications

> grails run-app

Spins up its own container that is bound to a port.  This container may have the ability to host multiple apps, but that isn't what you're doing when you type "run-app"